# Any solution to the Today Calculated Column problem is SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, formula

I would like to be able to use today's date in a calculated column in a SharePoint list to, for example, determine whether a task is overdue.  There is a well-documented trick that involves creating a dummy column named "Today," using it in a formula, and then deleting it, thereby "tricking" SharePoint into using the Today function.

The problem is that this method does not work reliably -- the calculation is not dynamic; it is only made when the item is saved, and therefore the Today "column" effectively becomes the Modified Date.  (This is probably why SharePoint won't let you use the Today function in a straight-forward way.)

Has anyone found a solution that works?  I know I can use javascript to get the actual date on the client side and display colors, flags, whatever, but I am looking for a "server side" solution.

---

For reference, the Today column trick and its problems are described fairly well at these two posts and associated comments:
http://blogs.msdn.com/cjohnson/archive/2006/03/16/552314.aspx and http://pathtosharepoint.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/calculated-columns-the-useless-today-trick/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There simply isn't a work around for this. As the values for the list are stored in the database and returned "as is" to other featurs such as the search crawler, a dynamic field cannot be created.

It is possible to create a custom field that will *display* the value using todays date in its calculation.

Comment: If future readers are considering coding a Today Calculated Column, you may wish to read about my experiences of trying to do exactly that: http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/08/how-not-to-develop-a-sharepointtoday-calculated-column/

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Christophe's (PathToSharePoint)'s article this also covers the Today trick and why it doesn't work

[The Truth about using Today in calculated columns](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2008/11/truth-about-using-today-in-calculated-columns/)

There are a number of fudges, probably the best one is Dessie's console app (mentioned above by MNM)

[Dynamically updating a SharePoint calculated column containing a Today reference](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dez/archive/2008/07/31/dynamically-updating-a-sharepoint-calculated-column-containing-a-quot-today-quot-reference.aspx)

Its good but its not perfect, for example you may have to worry about different timezones.

Before going down this route you should ask yourself if you really, really need to do this. For example :-

- If you want a [countdown (days overdue/days left to complete a task)](http://pathtosharepoint.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/a-countdown-for-tasks-lists/) then you can use SPD and a XLST Data View web part
- If you want a view to show overdue items or items created in the last X days ec then you can use [Today] in a views filter [2](http://www.sharepointblogs.com/dez/archive/2008/07/31/dynamically-updating-a-sharepoint-calculated-column-containing-a-quot-today-quot-reference.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Today column it needs to be updated. You can do that with either a timer job or by placing a jquery script on a page that is hit by the user. The script could call SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems to do the update. Pass a CAML clause so that you only update the list items where the Today value needs to be updated, e.g. once per day.

Comment: I would suggest to create a batch program to achieve that, let it run scheduled daily and the program will only update those date which is not equal to Today date. But I would like to see the script sample as what you mention. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to create your on field that does this calculation for you and then reference it in your SharePoint list.  Not a simple implementation but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution either, still no luck.. The Today column trick has the limitation of not being dynamic.

I do have one suggestion though, why don't we create a timer job that will update a certain a certain column with the current date every day at 12 AM. I know some of you all might think it an over head. Just my suggestion :D!!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a very rough, but working solution to this problem without having to do any coding. I'll explain both how i made the today column and how i worked that in to an overdue column, becuase that column was a pain to find out how to do as well.

First, I made a column named "today" (gasp!). Next I made a column named "Days Overdue". I then opened up sharepoint designer and created a new workflow. I set it to run every time an item is edited/updated (keep in mind I turned off versioning for this list, otherwise I would have had to resort to coding to avoid a bunch of useless data building up on our server). I set the actions to simply store the modified date in a workflow variable, then change the value of the today column to that variable. although the modified column is a date/time and my today column is just a date, it transfers just fine. I then set the workflow to pause for 2 hours. you can set this to whatever amount of time you want obviously, it will just change the latest possible time for your today column to update, i.e. 2AM in my case.

on to the days overdue column. this is the code for that guy -

```
=IF([Due Date]>Today,"None",IF([Date Closed]=0,Today-[Due Date],IF([Due Date]>[Date Closed],"None",IF(Today>=[Date Closed],[Date Closed]-[Due Date],IF([Due Date]<Today,Today-[Due Date])))))
```

This shows the days overdue in number form in days, or if its not overdue, it shows "None". You can use either a number format or a string format, but NOT A DATE FORMAT. Well, I hope this helps anyone who is running into this problem and doesn't want to have to delve into coding.

EDIT: I forgot to say that in the code above for the days overdue column, I put in that if today is past the date closed, to use the date closed minus the due date instead of today minus due date, to ensure that the calculation doesnt keep occurring after an item has been closed. you probably would have noticed that in the code, but i felt i should point it out just in case.

EDIT 2: The code I had in before my 2nd edit for my calculated column didn't calculate the days overdue properly after an issue had been marked "closed." I put in the updated code. The last part of the code doesn't make sense, as it is the same logic as the beginning, but it worked so I didn't want to take any chances! :)

Peace.

Comment: How would this update 'Days Overdue' if the item hadn't been modified for, say a week? Am I missing something?

Comment: my bad, i set the workflow to modify a dummy column after waiting the 2 hours, thus turning itself back on again.

Comment: This is kind of old, but could you please give me a step by step for this part: " I set the actions to simply store the modified date in a workflow variable, then change the value of the today column to that variable. although the modified column is a date/time and my today column is just a date, it transfers just fine. I then set the workflow to pause for 2 hours. you can set this to whatever amount of time you want obviously, it will just change the latest possible time for your today column to update, i.e. 2AM in my case."

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following and had no problems.

Field Name: Overdue

Field Type: Calculated

Data Type Returned: Yes/No

Formula:
`=AND([Due Date]<NOW(),Status<>"Completed",[Due Date]<>"")`

Comment: Doesn't work - will not update unless the record is updated. Check again tomorrow and you will see.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a workaround:

Create a date column called Today.
Use this column in your calculated formula (ignore the fact that the formula returns a wrong value).
After you are done with the formula, delete the Today column from your list.

For some reason it works this way! Now Sharepoint treats the Today in your formula as today's date.

Note: If you decide you want to change the formula, you have to create the Today column again. Otherwise, it wouldn't recognize Today as a valid column.

Answer (score -1):

I Tried @Farzad's approach and it seems to be working perfectly. I wanted to do a custom count on **Days Elapsed** so added a calculated column which previously I was using a difference between the **Created Date** and **Modified Date** Columns, which was only showing up whenever a user updated the post, much to my dismay.

I now have a formula which works as I would want to and uses the **Today** column, and here it is for anyone who would like to use it. I also have a Status column on the basis of which a base of On Hold is used, and the remaining formula are based on the date difference of **Today - Created**.

```
=IF(Status="On Hold","On Hold",IF(AND(Today=Created,(DATEDIF(Created,Today,"D")=0)),"New",IF(AND(Today<>Created,(DATEDIF(Created,Today,"D")=0)),"New (updated)",IF(DATEDIF(Created,Today,"d")>3,"Need Update Immediately",IF(DATEDIF(Created,Today,"d")=1,"One day old",IF(DATEDIF(Created,Today,"d")=2,"Two days old",""))))))
```

Basically its just a bunch of nested **IF** conditions which get me labels on the basis of which I can add a group to my view and filter out data if needed. Hope this helps anyone looking for an answer!