# How can I use [Today] in SharePoint to show current values of list items?

Tags: sharepoint

My list contains:
Item Name, Date of Purchase, Cost of Item, Daily Depreciation.

Basic case: an item depreciates $1 / day.

Since [Today] is 'Volatile', it cannot be used in a SharePoint formula.

I have seen solutions where users just create a few extra columns for dates in the future, and use formulas to calculate what the depreciation will be on those future dates.

I would like to actually have a column that says what the item is worth right now, and be able to total today's total value of all items.

Can anyone think of a good idea for doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to this question: [Today column in SharePoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878744/any-solution-to-the-today-calculated-column-problem-is-sharepoint)

You can try to use the mentioned workaround of creating a column named "Today" which fools SharePoint into allowing you to use it in formulas, but it has its limitations (e.g. you cannot update the list, and it only works for display).

The basic answer is you can't out-of-the-box.  One option would be to create a timer job which runs each day and updates the value in each item in the list.  It's not as efficient (or as simple) as you might like, but it might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the list as the datasource only for a report that provides the view you want.

Depending on the places where you wish to view the data, a [content query webpart can be customised](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241.aspx) to provide the data you need with a fairly low custom development requirement.

This does depend on having a reasonable handle on XSLT transformations.

Answer (score 0):

If you can limit the views then using a javascript script would do it, just display the Date of Purchase and cost and then use jquery to parse and do the math.

The biggest problem with this is that every place where you want to view this you will have to add the javascript code, there is not a simple column that can be added.