# Calculated Field- Sharepoint 2010 - Ageing

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns

Again a calculated field question, How can I create a calculated field to find out, **what is the age of the entry**.

In the list I will have a **created** date field, from that I would like to create **a number field calculating the no of days from created day to today**. I tried with =Today-Created, not working!!

Any inputs ? Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [DATEDIF function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx):

```
=DATEDIF(Created,Today,"D")
```

**UPDATE:**

Because `Today` won't work (see comments below), the OP chose a [completely different approach using XsltListViewWebPart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/22536/950).

Comment: Thank u, Marek for spending time on it, However we do have a problem in dynamic update with Today, Is't it?

Comment: @Jithu You're right! I forgot that the calculated column value changes only when the item is created or edited. It has been [discussed before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/878744/95).

Comment: Hi Marek, I asked [_the same question here_](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22536/calculated-field-formula-for-ageing), got a good answer from Mr Omlin. By using XsltListViewWebPart. So I think I will select your answer, so that the other user can access the said answer!!